# Is there a method to add 10 Data items into collection in BluePrism?

Tags: blueprism

I want to add 10 Data items into collection, the collection is empty and it contains one field, i want to add all the data items into this collection

Comment: Why not just use the `Collection` VBO's `Add Row` collection, then a calculation stage setting the row to the value of the data item...? This is pretty rudimentary functionality, have you completed the Foundation training?

Comment: I see that you are an amateur in BluePrism, i say that i want to add 10 data items not one, so as you say, i must Use 10 add row and 10 calculation?

Comment: Unless you want to write your own utility VBO and associated code stage, this is exactly the way I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you can do it in few different ways:

1) Using calculation stage

[image: Example]

2) Using Loop. You would loop through input collection and inside of each loop you would first add new row to the output collection and using calculation stage, write the value there.

3) By operating on collections. You could maybe use actions like "Utility - Collection manipulation:Delete column" and "Utility - Collection manipulation:Rename Column" and other if needed, to ensure that the incoming collection will match the desired outgoing collection.